# What is the solution of the integral (product of two standard normal CDFs)?

Tags: probability-distributions, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I need to compute this kind of integral:

[image]

where $b>0,d>0,a,c$ and $e$ are known constants and $\Phi$ is the CDF of the standard Normal distribution.

Comment: Just making sure, $\Phi()$ is the CDF of the standard Normal Distribution right? Please write it in your question.